# MySQL and PHP Many-to-Many Database Relationships

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to advance my knowledge of SQL queries but am getting stuck on a many-to-many relationship query.

Using PHP and MySQL database structure is as follows:

Database structure:

```
--------------------------------------------
|                  colour                  |
--------------------------------------------
| colour_id         |      colour          |
--------------------------------------------
| 1                 |      blue            |
--------------------------------------------
| 2                 |      red             |
--------------------------------------------
############################################
--------------------------------------------
```

.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   product_colours                                             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| id            |     product_id       |    colour_id           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1             |         1            |         2              |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2             |         2            |         1              |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
#################################################################
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

**MAIN TABLE**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   products                                                    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| id          |      name               |      details          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1           |      product 1          |      blah             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2           |      product 2          |      blah             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
#################################################################
-----------------------------------------------------------------


-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    product_group_names                                        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| id            |      product_id         |    group_name_id    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1             |          1              |         1           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2             |          2              |         2           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
#################################################################
-----------------------------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------
|        group_name                        |
--------------------------------------------
| group_name_id     |      group_name      |
--------------------------------------------
| 1                 |  product_group_1     |
--------------------------------------------
| 2                 |  product_group_2     |
--------------------------------------------
############################################
--------------------------------------------
```

Could I write one query using joins which says: `SELECT * colours WHERE group_name = product_group_1`?

Any help would be amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes you could write such a query - what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly write a query to do that. You'll need to basically join your tables together so you can link the data you need from table to table, and then add a where clause for your desired condition.

Your colours are "linked" to your `product_colours` via the `colour_id` attribute, the product colours are linked to the `product_group_names` via the `product_id` attributes on both tables, and your group names are linked via the `group_name_id` and `group_id` attributes on the `group_names` table.

When you're doing this kind of query though, if you have a lot of records in these tables - the queries can go very slow. You need to make sure you add indicies on each of the columns referenced in the `JOIN...ON` clauses, as well as the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT colour FROM colours c
JOIN product_colours pc ON c.id = pc.colour_id
JOIN product_group_names pgn ON pgn.product_id = pc.product_id
JOIN group_name gn ON gn.id = pgn.group_name_id
WHERE gn.group_name = "product_group_1"
```